# python, gae, ndb, override a class method, but it needs to apply to the instance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How to override an inherited class method, that needs to query for specific properties on the child class?

I'm not sure how to go about this. This is what I've got:

```
    class base_class:

        @classmethod
        def a_method(cls, something):
            return ndb.Query(kind=cls.__name__).fetch(keys_only=True)

        @classmethod
            def calls_a_method(cls, size=1, soemthing):

                 entity_keys = cls.a_method(something)

    class child_class(base_class):

         a_property = ndb.BooleanProperty()

         def another_method():
             stuff =  child_class.calls_a_method() #?
```

How do I override a_method from the base_class, such that it will also filter out keys where a_property = False for the child_class?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you break up the query across the methods, you can construct a custom query in the child class:

```
class base_class:

    @classmethod
    def a_method(cls, something):
        return ndb.Query(kind=cls.__name__)

    @classmethod
    def calls_a_method(cls, size=1, something):
        entity_keys = cls.a_method(something).fetch(keys_only=True)

class child_class(base_class):

    a_property = ndb.BooleanProperty()

    @classmethod
    def another_method(cls):
        q = cls.a_method(something).filter(cls.a_property == False)
        entity_keys = q.fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Comment: That is close to the solution I ended up using. `return ndb.Query(kind=cls.__name__).filter(child_class.public == True).fetch(keys_only=True) `.  In the child class, but still using 'a_method' as the class method.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
    class base_class(ndb.Model):
            @classmethod
            def a_method(cls, something):
                    return cls.Query().fetch(keys_only=True)

            @classmethod
            def calls_a_method(cls, something):
                    entity_keys = cls.a_method(something)

    class child_class(base_class):
            a_property = ndb.BooleanProperty()

            @classmethod
            def another_method(cls, value):
                    return cls.calls_a_method(value)

            @classmethod
            def a_method(cls, something):
                    return cls.query(cls.a_property==something).fetch(keys_only=True)
```